# What is pixel width and length for jspdf's default 'a4' format?

Tags: javascript, size, jspdf

What is the size in pixels for jspdf's 'a4' format?
I want to add an image to pdf so it will take full width of the document.

```
new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [ 595.28,  841.89])
```

In the sourcecode on GitHub you can see the [supported units](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/ddbfc0f0250ca908f8061a72fa057116b7613e78/jspdf.js#L791) (relative proportions to pt), and you can also see the [default page formats](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/ddbfc0f0250ca908f8061a72fa057116b7613e78/jspdf.js#L59) (with their **sizes in pt**).

Hope this could help,

Laura.

Answer (score 11):

## A4 pixel dimensions: `793.706 x 1,122.52` pixels

Use this helper function to convert jsPDF points to other units (based on @lmerlo's answer and the original source)

```js
function convertPointsToUnit(points, unit) {
  // Unit table from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/ddbfc0f0250ca908f8061a72fa057116b7613e78/jspdf.js#L791
  var multiplier;
  switch(unit) {
    case 'pt':  multiplier = 1;          break;
    case 'mm':  multiplier = 72 / 25.4;  break;
    case 'cm':  multiplier = 72 / 2.54;  break;
    case 'in':  multiplier = 72;         break;
    case 'px':  multiplier = 96 / 72;    break;
    case 'pc':  multiplier = 12;         break;
    case 'em':  multiplier = 12;         break;
    case 'ex':  multiplier = 6;
    default:
      throw ('Invalid unit: ' + unit);
  }
  return points * multiplier;
}
```